# Somar valor de índices de mesmo nome no array PHP

Tags: php

Opa pessoal,
como faço para somar os valores dos índices que tem o mesmo nome no php, estou usando o laravel caso tenha alguma função extra.

Print:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Produto] => chocolate
        [Quantidade] => 300
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Produto] => morango
        [Quantidade] => 150
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Produto] => chocolate
        [Quantidade] => 400
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Produto] => morango
        [Quantidade] => 200
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Produto] => cacau
        [Quantidade] => 40
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Produto] => chocolate
        [Quantidade] => 250
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [Produto] => morango
        [Quantidade] => 125
    )
```

Gostaria desse resultado:
Chocolate: 950
morango: 475
cacau: 40

somar os valores que tem o mesmo índice;

desde já agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplificando o codigo do Augusto Vasques, e retornando o resultado no mesmo formato de entrada:

```
<?php

$vendas = array(
    [ "Produto" => "chocolate", "Quantidade" => 300 ],
    [ "Produto" => "morango"  , "Quantidade" => 150 ],
    [ "Produto" => "chocolate", "Quantidade" => 400 ],
    [ "Produto" => "morango",   "Quantidade" => 200 ],
    [ "Produto" => "cacau",     "Quantidade" => 40  ],
    [ "Produto" => "chocolate", "Quantidade" => 250 ],
    [ "Produto" => "morango",   "Quantidade" => 125 ]
);

$venda_sabor = [];

//Para cada sabor soma as respectivas vendas.
foreach($vendas as $key=>$value){
  if (isset($venda_sabor[$value["Produto"]]))
    $venda_sabor[$value["Produto"]] += $value["Quantidade"];
  else
    $venda_sabor[$value["Produto"]] = $value["Quantidade"];
}

$vendas = [];

//Retornando para o formato original
foreach($venda_sabor as $key=>$value){
  $vendas[] = [ "Produto" => $key, "Quantidade" => $value ];
}

//Imprime o resultado
print_r($vendas);
```

Retorno:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => chocolate
            [Quantidade] => 950
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => morango
            [Quantidade] => 475
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => cacau
            [Quantidade] => 40
        )

)
```

Comment: muito obrigado Jader, simplificou e resolveu. grato

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$vendas = array(
    [ "Produto" => "chocolate", "Quantidade" => 300 ],
    [ "Produto" => "morango"  , "Quantidade" => 150 ],
    [ "Produto" => "chocolate", "Quantidade" => 400 ],
    [ "Produto" => "morango",   "Quantidade" => 200 ],
    [ "Produto" => "cacau",     "Quantidade" => 40  ],
    [ "Produto" => "chocolate", "Quantidade" => 250 ],
    [ "Produto" => "morango",   "Quantidade" => 125 ]
);

//Lista os sabores pela coluna Produto desprezando os valores duplicados 
//e permuta as chaves com os valores.
$venda_sabor = array_flip(array_column($vendas, "Produto"));

//Ajusta as vendas de cada sabor em 0.
$venda_sabor = array_fill_keys(array_keys($venda_sabor), 0);

//Para cada sabor soma as respectivas vendas.
foreach($vendas as $key=>$value){
  $venda_sabor[$value["Produto"]] += $value["Quantidade"];
}

//Imprime o resultado
print_r($venda_sabor);
//Array
//(
//  [chocolate] => 950
//  [morango] => 475
//  [cacau] => 40
//)
```

Código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/MildDisguisedLists#main.php)

---

Funções utilizadas:

[`array_flip()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-flip.php): Permuta todas as chaves e seus valores associados em um array.

[`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php): Retorna os valores de uma coluna do array informado.

[`array_fill_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-fill-keys.php): Preenche um array com valores, especificando chaves.

[`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php): Retorna todas as chaves ou uma parte das chaves de um array.

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo, o codigo de Jader também funcionou!